# What is a "Bourbaki Talk"?

Tags: terminology

I've seen lately many people using this concept. I have searched the web, but there's no answer. 
Anyone knows what does a "Bourbaki Talk" mean?

Note: I am knowledgeable about the Bourbaki group. Nevertheless, I have never heard of the concept "Bourbaki Talk".

EDIT (after answer): A recent example is here: https://valuevar.wordpress.com/2017/01/14/bourbaki-talk/

Comment: Can you place this into context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki

Comment: I don't believe this has any specific context. People who announce their seminar talk or whatever, simply describe it as "I'm giving a Bourbaki talk". Thus, I'm quite certain that for these people this is a self-evident concept. Of course they are completely wrong, but it is usual that people often assume that what they know is universal and well-known.

Comment: Are your referring to the "Séminaires Bourbaki" ? http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/

Comment: Thanks Jagy. But how does this explains it? I have read even a book about the Bourbaki group, and still I have no idea what this concept means. I can guess it might mean some very rigorous talk, but this is a guess.

Comment: See @anderstood's comment.

Comment: Thanks anderstood. I don't read french, sorry. (And haven't seen it written in french or by french people). What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not the best person to talk about "Séminaires Bourbaki" but i) Bourbaki is a fictitious mathematician, see Will Jagy's link, ii) he gave his name to seminars, created in 1952 and mostly in French. I guess that saying "I've given a Bourbaki talk" means "I have given a talk in Séminaire Bourbaki", which is very prestigious (I guess).

Comment: No, this is not the meaning. People are saying this NOW, at THIS moment. They announce a future "Bourbaki Talk". Is this seminar series still going on?

Comment: But why don't you ask them what they mean when they say it?!?!

Comment: (yes, Bourbaki seminars are held every year)

Comment: I don't know them. These are announcements on the web!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, ah, you are correct! They mean the specific french seminar!!!!

Comment: You can see [these explanations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Séminaire_Nicolas_Bourbaki). The ‘Séminaire  Bourbaki’ happens four times a year,  at the Institut Henri Poincaré in Paris (january, march, june and november, on saturdays). The talks are not necessarily in French.

Comment: You should provide context. As it is, your question is unanswerable: you are asking what some people who you do not mention mean when they say something somewhere on the web. Do you have a link, a name, something? Do you see how this is somewhat absurd?

Comment: Provided the context now.

Comment: That link you included quite clearly explains what a Bourbaki talk is...

Comment: Hence, I explain it was discovered after the answer. The initial announcments did not include explanations of the term.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the comments I found the answer (the problem was that on the web it is referred to always in French, and not English, hence it is virtually undiscoverable, except for French speakers) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9minaire_Nicolas_Bourbaki):

“*The Séminaire Nicolas Bourbaki (Bourbaki Seminar) is a series of seminars (in fact public lectures with printed notes distributed) that has been held in Paris since 1948. It is one of the major institutions of contemporary mathematics, and a barometer of mathematical achievement, fashion, and reputation. It is named after Nicolas Bourbaki, a group of French and other mathematicians of variable membership.”*

A Bourbaki talk is always given by a speaker about other people’s work. It is accompanied by an expository paper explaining difficult recent material.

Comment: "A Bourbaki talk is always given by a speaker about other people’s work." Well, there were well-known exceptions to this in the past...